# OpenMDAO Error: object has no attribute '_post_setup_vars'

Tags: python

I'm building a new OpenMDAO component. I do:

```
prob = Problem(impl=impl, root=myNewComponent(nTurbs=4, rotor_diameter=126.0))
prob.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
prob.driver.add_desvar('turbineX')
prob.driver.add_objective('AEP')
prob.setup()
prob.run()
```

..And OpenMDAO crashes with `AttributeError: 'myNewComponent' object has no attribute '_post_setup_vars'`. What does this message mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put `super(myNewComponent, self).__init__()` in your component's `__init__` function.